# Batch files what does the following mean?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to know what the following means exactly so I could debug a batch file program. (Where `root` is a variable that holds a string)

```
    set tst=!tst:%root%=!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string %root% is being removed from the string tst. See

```
SET /?
```

Also not that delayed expansion must be enabled for the line as you have it shown.